# I run the libimobiledevice getting started code, got err?

Tags: c, libimobiledevice

I use gcc to complile the code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libimobiledevice/lockdown.h>
#include <libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice.h>
#include <plist/plist.h>

int main()
{
    static char *udid = NULL;

    /* Device Handle */
    idevice_t device = NULL;

    /* Try to connect to first USB device */
    if (idevice_new_with_options(&device, NULL, IDEVICE_LOOKUP_USBMUX) != IDEVICE_E_SUCCESS) {
        printf("ERROR: No device found!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Retrieve the udid of the connected device */
    if (idevice_get_udid(device, &udid) != IDEVICE_E_SUCCESS) {
    printf("ERROR: Unable to get the device UDID.\n");
    idevice_free(device);
    return -1;
    }

    /* Outputs device identifier */
    printf("Connected with UDID: %s\n", udid);

    /* Cleanup */
    idevice_free(device);
    free(udid);
}
```

got

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_idevice_free", referenced from:
_main in 1-af7b2e.o
"_idevice_get_udid", referenced from:
_main in 1-af7b2e.o
"_idevice_new_with_options", referenced from:
_main in 1-af7b2e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

while I have tried `gcc -lstdc++ hello.c -o hello` it's still cann't be compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `libimobiledevice` library, try this:

`gcc hello.c -o hello -limobiledevice-1.0`